# Figure date format from string in ruby

Tags: ruby, oracle, datetime-format

I am working in a simple data loader for text files and would like to add a feature for correctly loading dates into the tables. The problem I have is that I do not know the date format before hand, and it will not be my script doing the inserts - it has to generate insert statements for later use.

The `Date.parse` is almost what I'd need. If there was a way to grab the format it identified on the string in a way I could use to generate a `to_date(...)`(Oracle standard) would be perfect.

An example:

My input file:

```
user_name;birth_date
Sue;20130427
Amy;31/4/1984
```

Should generate:

```
insert into my_table values ('Sue', to_date('20130427','yyyymmdd'));
insert into my_table values ('Amy', to_date('31/4/1984','dd/mm/yyyy'));
```

Note that it is important the original string remains unchanged - so I cannot parse it to a standard format used in the inserts (it is a requirement).

At the moment I am just testing a bunch of regexes and doing some validation, but I was wondering if there was a more robust way.

Comment: Interesting question, well-stated.

Comment: How about using [Date#strptime](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime): iterate over the range of possible format strings until a date object is returned?  You would have to `rescue` exceptions, of course.

Comment: This is impossible. Given `3/7/1984`, how would you know if this is March 7th, 1984 or July 3rd, 1984? Given `050601`, how would you know if this is May 6th, 2001, June 5th, 2001, or June 1st, 2005, etc.?

Comment: @sawa, unless it's always one or the other, following a rule, which I would think likely, considering it's from an input file.  filippo?

Comment: @CarySwoveland I don't fully understand your comment. Are you writing that the format should be consistent throughout a file, and once you find an unambiguous string, that will disambiguate other occurrences of a string in that file?

Comment: @CarySwoveland correct. as you may have guessed, I'm not really trying to generate all these inserts but rather figuring out which format should the inserts be generated for a given file. Each file however will have a consistent content as far as format goes.

Comment: @CarySwoveland thanks for the idea ``Date#strptime`` would be similar to the regexes I'm using but maybe more appropriate. Might change to that if I don't find anything better.

Comment: @sawa my files will have so many samples that I can always assume I have at least one non-ambiguous date do work with. That, besides the fact that within a file the date format remains the same (although it may change from file to file)

Comment: Hmmm.  Are you saying that if the first date in a file is `xx/xx/xx` you may have to read a few records to determine whether it's `mm/dd/yy` or `dd/mm/yy`?  I suggest you edit the question to clarify.

Comment: @CarySwoveland well, yes. that would be it, but not really my concern at this point. As I said to sawa, lets just assume all dates are unambiguous for now, I have a few options to avoid the mm/dd|dd/mm if I know the format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose (using for example `String#scan`), you extracted an array of the date strings from a single file. It may be like:

```
strings = ["20130427", "20130102", ...]
```

Prepare in advance an array of all formats you can think of. It may be like:

```
Formats = ["%Y%m%d", "%y%m%d", "%y/%m/%d", "%m/%d/%y", "%d/%m/%y", ...]
```

Then check all formats that can parse all of the strings:

```
require "date"
formats =
Formats.select{|format| strings.all?{|s| Date.strptime(s, format) rescue nil}}
```

If this array `formats` includes exactly one element, then that means the strings were unambiguously parsed with that format. Using that format, you can go back to the strings and parse them with that format.

Otherwise, either you failed to provide the appropriate format within `Formats`, or the strings remained ambiguous.

Comment: Note the first line of the OP's example; no match might be OK. Since all records in a file have the same date format, I'd think you could improve efficiency by reading records until a date string matched exactly one format (which could be the first record). If the first record matched (say) two formats and a subsequent record matched neither of those, you've got a data problem.  If all records matched the same (say) two date formats, ambiguity remains.  Whether you want to check the file for consistency of the date format is a separate question.

Comment: From the OP's comments, I understand that consistency is guaranteed for each file.

Comment: I still don't see why you need `strings.all?`.  Wouldn't the following be more efficient? `formats = Formats.select {|f| <strings.first match f> }`.  If `formats.size` is zero or one, you're done; else `str = strings[1..-1].find { |s| <s matches zero or one of the formats in formats> }`.  In the last case, ambiguity remains if `str` is `nil`, else `fmt = formats.select {|f| <str match f> }` and the format is `fmt.first` if `fmt.size` is one, else there is a problem with the data.

Comment: @sawa pretty cool. Although it is pretty much testing a bunch of formats (like I'm currently doing) it looks better and handles the mm/dd|dd/mm issue. Already better than mine. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [Chronic](https://github.com/mojombo/chronic) gem. It will extract dates in most formats.

It has options to resolve the ambiguity in the xx/xx/xxxx format, but you'd have to specify which to prefer when either match.

Comment: *you'd have to specify which [format] to use*--The OP is asking how to do that automatically. That is the whole point of the question.

Comment: I think it answers his question, but his followup comments indicate he needs to determine which format to prefer on a per-file basis, which is what your answer covers. Combining my answer and your answer would give him a 100% solution.

Comment: Mark, the problem is that filippo needs the format string corresponding to a date string, which I don't think is provided by that gem.

Comment: Indeed, that's a strange requirement. I would challenge the need for it. Why not create a normalized SQL insert string? Could include the original string in comments, if that was wanted in the output.